# Adding JAR with ObjectMapper makes my ObjectMapper non-discoverable

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, swagger

How can I make my object mapper work in situation when there is another object mapper defined in jar from dependencies ?

I'm trying to use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) with [Jersey 2](https://jersey.java.net/) which is being run under Jetty. The problem is that as soon as I add Swagger JAX-RX jar into classpath my object mapper is not discovered therefore I lose custom serialization of my objects.

Here is how my object mapper defined

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
}
```

I've posted [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/862) to Swagger's maintainers where you could read details.

After hours of debugging in internals of Jersey I found that Swagger's own object mapper [com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/scala/com/wordnik/swagger/jaxrs/json/JacksonJsonProvider.java) calls `super.setMapper(commonMapper)` that sets non-null value to `ProviderBase._mapperConfig._mapper`. Later when http request handler attempts to serialize instance of my class call ends up in `ProviderBase.locateMapper` which has following body

```
public MAPPER locateMapper(Class<?> type, MediaType mediaType)
{
    // First: were we configured with a specific instance?
    MAPPER m = _mapperConfig.getConfiguredMapper();
    if (m == null) {
        // If not, maybe we can get one configured via context?
        m = _locateMapperViaProvider(type, mediaType);
        if (m == null) {
            // If not, let's get the fallback default instance
            m = _mapperConfig.getDefaultMapper();
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

in correct code-flow `_mapperConfig.getConfiguredMapper()` returns null which subsequently causes invocation of `_locateMapperViaProvider` which finds my custom mapper. With Swagger it defaults to `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JsonMapperConfigurator` and my custom json serializers never get invoked.

I created small project which reproduces this problem [here](https://github.com/cppexpert/broken_swagger_jaxrs_integration).

How would you guys suggest to fix this ? I could probably specify deserializer on each property of type `TTLocalDate` but it'll pollute the code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by fehguy in the issue report, using the latest Swagger release and using the `SwaggerSerializers` should fix this issue. Where previously the Swagger `JacksonJsonProvider` would be used for *all* serializions, the `SwaggerSerializers` is [only used for the `Swagger` model object](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-jaxrs/src/main/java/io/swagger/jaxrs/listing/SwaggerSerializers.java#L21)

```
public class SwaggerSerializers implements MessageBodyWriter<Swagger> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations,
                               MediaType mediaType) {
        return Swagger.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }
```