# Jersey parsing Java 8 date time

Tags: java, datetime, jersey, jax-rs, java-8

This is my user class, and I to save ISO compliant date time in my database.

```
public class User  {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String email;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime loginDate;

 }
```

Here is my Jersey controller:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")

public Response create(  User user) {

    Map<Object, Object> apiResponse = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    Map<Object, Object> response  = new HashMap<Object, Object>();


    user = (User) userService.create(user);

}
```

How can can I consume a datetime format like this one in jersey? Is it possible to send a datatime `String` and create Java 8 date time object automatically?

```
{        
    "email" : "imz.mrz@gmail.com"
    "loginDate" : "2015-04-17T06:06:51.465Z"
}
```

#

Update:

I was using Spring boot jersey, and had other jsr packages

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

So I removed all the packages except from spring-boot-jersey package. 
use this annotation for LocalDateTime

```
  @JsonDeserialize(using =  LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
```

This way I can consume ISODate and save ISODate() to mongodb and produce full formated mongodb LocalDateTime to frontend.

Problem solved.

Comment: There's probably a library that someone has written to do this, if not, you might need to write your own custom converter. See http://blog.dejavu.sk/2014/02/11/inject-custom-java-types-via-jax-rs-parameter-annotations/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### *Couple options I see...*

#### Option 1:

Assuming you have JAXB annotation support with Jackson as the JSON provider...

You could use an `XmlAdapter`. For example

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return dateTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime dateTime) throws Exception {
        Instant instant = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(instant);
    }
}
```

<sup>See the [Instant API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) for more information.</sup>

Then you can just annotate the field/property with the adapter

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime loginDate;
```

You could also declare the annotation at the package level, so that all uses in the package will use the adapter, without the need to annotate. You do so in a file named `package-info.java` put inside the package

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalDateTime.class, 
                        value = LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package thepackage.of.the.models;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

#### Option 2:

Use the Jackson APIs directly. Meaning, use a `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonSerializer`. For example

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, 
            DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
        TextNode node = (TextNode)codec.readTree(jp);
        String dateString = node.textValue();
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return dateTime;
    } 
}

public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime dateTime, JsonGenerator jg, 
            SerializerProvider sp) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Instant instant = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        jg.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(instant));
    } 
}
```

You can apply this at the field/property level

```
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
public LocalDateTime loginDate;
```

Or at the `ObjectMapper` level (so you don't need to annotate everywhere)

```
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer());
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        // add JAXB annotation support if required
        mapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }  
}
```

Basically what happens, is that the `MessageBodyWriter`/`MessageBodyReader` used for ummarshalling/marshalling, will call the `getContext` method to get the `ObjectMapper`

**Note:**

- The above solutions will parse from the format `2007-12-03T10:15:30.00Z`, as documented in [`Instant.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), and will serialize to the same format, as documented in [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT)
- The above is also assuming you are using Jackson as the Serializer. I used the below dependency (with Jersey 2.16) to test

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.16</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  The dependency uses a `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` for JAXB annotation support. If you are using a lower version of Jersey like 1.x, the `jersey-json` dependency should offer JAXB annotation support, if you enable the POJO mapping feature. Alternatively for Jersey 1.x, if you want to use Jackson 2, you can use this dependency

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

  which is actually what is used by `jersey-media-json-jackson`. So you could explicitly register the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`, or add the Jackson package (`com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json`) to list packages to scan

---

### UPDATE

**See Also:**

- [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28802544/2587435). There is Jackson Module that already comes with serializers for the Java 8 date/time APIs.

Comment: Thanks for very descriptive answer, I'm going with option 2. 
Now I can save the it in mongodb with this format 
 "loginDate" : { "dateTime" : ISODate("2015-04-17T10:06:51.465Z"), "offset" : { "_id" : "Z", "totalSeconds" : 0 } }

However when try to Serilalize it it doesn't work. It gives me 

"No property null found on entity class java.time.OffsetDateTime to bind constructor parameter to!"

Comment: Changed the it LocalDateTime, still getting the error when try to retrieve the Object 
"No property null found on entity class java.time.LocalDateTime to bind constructor parameter to"

Comment: It work fine for me. Which configuration are you using? Annotation or ObjectMapper?

Comment: In the `ContextResolver` I forgot the register the `SimpleModule` :-) `mapper.registerModule(module);` Made edit.

Comment: I'm using annotations , if I use objectmapper how should I use it ?

Comment: The annotations should work. I've tested all the options above. As for how to use the `ObjectMapper`, if you are scanning for all your resource classes (ones annotated with `@Path`), then the `ContextResolver` should automatically be picked up with the `@Provider` annotation. No extra configuration is required. I would put a print statement in the `getContext` method to see if it is called when serializing. Let me know. Also have you tried deserializing? Does _that_ work?

Comment: yes deserializing works.  About serializing  I don't think its a jersey issue, with this case we are saving the data as ISO() format.  Mongo db can't retrieve the data. However thanks for your help

Comment: Cleaning up all jersey related packages except 
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
 <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>

Solved the problem for me. I ended up not using serialization. 
Thanks for your help.