# Using Jersey client, problems with Java 8 Date API (Jsr310)

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jsr310

I'm doing a little PoC using jersey client to consume a REST service and I'm having problems with a field that is in LocalDateTime format. 
The REST service response is like this:

```
{
    "id": 12,
    "infoText": "Info 1234",
    "creationDateTime": "2001-12-12T13:40:30"
}
```

And my entity class:

```
package com.my.poc.jerseyclient;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Info {

    private Long id;
    private String infoText;
    private LocalDateTime creationDateTime;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getInfoText() {
        return infoText;
    }

    public void setInfoText(String infoText) {
        this.infoText = infoText;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreationDateTime() {
        return creationDateTime;
    }

    public void setCreationDateTime(LocalDateTime creationDateTime) {
        this.creationDateTime = creationDateTime;
    }

}
```

The dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

My code doing a GET /api/info/123 with jersey client:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
WebTarget webTarget = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api/").path("info/");
Response response = webTarget.path("123").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get();
System.out.println("GET Body (object): " + response.readEntity(Info.class));
```

And I'm getting an exception like this:

```
...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDateTime] from String value ('2001-12-12T13:40:30'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@21b2e768; line: 1, column: 32] (through reference chain: com.my.poc.jerseyclient.Info["creationDateTime"])
...
```

What am I missing? I tried this with RestTemplate (Spring rest client), and it works perfectly without any configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jsr310 module still needs to be registered with Jackson. You can do that in a [`ContextResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ContextResolver.html) as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803634/2587435), where you register the `Jsr310Module` with the `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
```

You an then register the `ContextResolver` with the client. What will happen is that the `JacksonJsonProvider` should call the `getContext` method, and retrieve the `ObjectMapper` to be used for (de)serialization.

You can also use the same `ContextResolver` on the server side. If you only need this functionality on the client, another way is to simple construct the `JacksonJsonProvider` with the `ObjectMapper`. A little bit simpler

```
new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper)
```

Comment: It works, thanks! I was thinking that I had to register it with the client in some manner, but I didn't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Putting it all together for client functionality:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());

JacksonJsonProvider provider = new JacksonJsonProvider(mapper);
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(new ClientConfig().register(provider));
```

Comment: Thanks for stating the answer so clearly and cleanly. Note that since Jackson 2.6.0 the `JSR310Module` is deprecated in favor of the `JavaTimeModule`.