# Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDate]

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

```
{
"toDepartureDate": "2016-12-28",
"fromDepartureDate": "2016-12-28"
}
```

I want to post above String dates in json as `java.time.LocalDate`, but I am receiving 400 Bad Request as error. Could some one help here. I have used `@JsonFormat` but it did not help me either.

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "GMT+5:30")

private LocalDate fromDepartureDate;

@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING,pattern="yyyy-MM-dd",timezone = "GMT+5:30")
private LocalDate toDepartureDate;

{
  "timestamp": 1482942147246,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.validation.BindException",
  "errors": [
    {
      "codes": [
        "typeMismatch.flightReportSearchDto.fromDepartureDate",
        "typeMismatch.fromDepartureDate",
        "typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate",
        "typeMismatch"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "flightReportSearchDto.fromDepartureDate",
            "fromDepartureDate"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "fromDepartureDate",
          "code": "fromDepartureDate"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDate] for property 'fromDepartureDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '2016-12-28'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2016-12-28]",
      "objectName": "flightReportSearchDto",
      "field": "fromDepartureDate",
      "rejectedValue": "2016-12-28",
      "bindingFailure": true,
      "code": "typeMismatch"
    },
    {
      "codes": [
        "typeMismatch.flightReportSearchDto.toDepartureDate",
        "typeMismatch.toDepartureDate",
        "typeMismatch.java.time.LocalDate",
        "typeMismatch"
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "codes": [
            "flightReportSearchDto.toDepartureDate",
            "toDepartureDate"
          ],
          "arguments": null,
          "defaultMessage": "toDepartureDate",
          "code": "toDepartureDate"
        }
      ],
      "defaultMessage": "Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.time.LocalDate] for property 'toDepartureDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat java.time.LocalDate] for value '2016-12-29'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value [2016-12-29]",
      "objectName": "flightReportSearchDto",
      "field": "toDepartureDate",
      "rejectedValue": "2016-12-29",
      "bindingFailure": true,
      "code": "typeMismatch"
    }
  ]
 
}
```

Comment: Look like a duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format

Answer (score 5):

Add in your date property

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)

The previous answer works fine for me. Only add, that if you need to change date format, you can use this sentence:

th:value="${#temporals.format(fromDepartureDate,'yyyy-MM-dd')}"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in your model class instead of @JsonFormat

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class YourModelClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4399291572854602191L;
    ...
    ...
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("toDepartureDate")
    private LocalDate toDepartureDate;
    ....
    ....
  }
```

`@JsonProperty` annotation should be help to get data with key name.
`private LocalDate toDepartureDate` line is defining your variables type for your model class. If the correct data entered , it will be assigned correctly.
And also with serilization and deserilization like as below , it worked for me .