# Jackson: deserialize epoch to LocalDate

Tags: java, json, jackson, epoch, localdate

I have following JSON:

```
{
      "id" : "1",
      "birthday" : 401280850089
}
```

And POJO class:

```
public class FbProfile {
    long id;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    LocalDate birthday;
}
```

I am using Jackson to do deserialization:

```
public FbProfile loadFbProfile(File file) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    FbProfile profile = mapper.readValue(file, FbProfile.class);
    return profile;
}
```

But it throws an exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token
>   (VALUE_NUMBER_INT), expected VALUE_STRING: Expected array or string.

How can I deserialize epoch to `LocalDate`? I would like to add that if I change the datatype from `LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` it works perfectly fine. So maybe it's better to deserialize to `java.util.Date` and create the getter and setter which will do the conversion to/from `LocalDate`.

Comment: Please be aware that converting milliseconds to date is time zone dependent. For example, the number in you example equals 1982-09-19T10:54:10.089Z, which in turn equals 1982-09-18T23:54:10.089-11:00[Pacific/Midway].

Comment: Avoid the oldfashioned `Date` class. The only thing it gives you that modern classes don’t is trouble. If you want to try other classes than `LocalDate`, `Instant` is the obvious choice.

Comment: Did you search prior to asking? I am thinking you may find some inspiration in [this question: Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format).

Comment: @Ole V.V. Yes I searched. I found annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)` but it doesn't work with epoch. Nevertheless thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 10):

I've managed to do it writing my own deserializer (thank you @Ole V.V. to point me to the post [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)):

```
public class LocalDateTimeFromEpochDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected LocalDateTimeFromEpochDeserializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return Instant.ofEpochMilli(jp.readValueAs(Long.class)).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
    }

}
```

Notice about timezone is also very useful. Thank you!

The still open question is if it can be done without writing own deserializer?

Comment: This is a guess: my guess is if you insist on serializing between `LocalDate` and milliseconds since the Epoch, you will need your own deserializer. If you could substitute the long milliseconds with a formatted date string *or* you would accept getting an `Instant` instead of a `LocalDate`, I would be more optimistic about using the built-in deserialization. Said having barely scratched the surface of Jackson. Glad you found a way through.

Answer (score 3):

Another option that I went with if you have the ability to change the POJO, is to just declare your field as `java.time.Instant`.

```
public class FbProfile {
    long id;
    Instant birthday;
}
```

This will deserialize from a number of different formats including epoch.  Then if you need to use it as a `LocalDate` or something else in your business logic, simply do what some of the converters above are doing:

```
LocalDate asDate = birthday.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()
```

or

```
LocalDateTime asDateTime = birthday.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it without writing a custom deserializer, but it'll require some modifications.

First, the `LocalDateDeserializer` accepts a custom `DateTimeFormatter`. So, we need to create a formatter that accepts an epoch millis. I did this by joining the `INSTANT_SECONS` and `MILLI_OF_SECOND` fields:

```
// formatter that accepts an epoch millis value
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // epoch seconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS, 1, 19, SignStyle.NEVER)
    // milliseconds
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
    // create formatter, using UTC as timezone
    .toFormatter().withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

I also set the formatter with UTC zone, so it won't be affected by timezones and DST changes.

Then, I've created the deserializer and registered in my `ObjectMapper`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
// add the LocalDateDeserializer with the custom formatter
module.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(formatter));
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

I also had to remove the annotation from the `birthday` field (because the annotation seems to override the module configuration):

```
public class FbProfile {
    long id;

    // remove @JsonDeserialize annotation
    LocalDate birthday;
}
```

And now the big issue: as the `DateTimeFormatter` accepts only `String` as input, and the JSON contains a number in `birthday` field, I had to change the JSON:

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "birthday" : "401280850089"
}
```

Note that I changed `birthday` to a `String` (put the value between quotes).

With this, the `LocalDate` is read from JSON correctly:

```
FbProfile value = mapper.readValue(json, FbProfile.class);
System.out.println(value.getBirthday()); // 1982-09-19
```

---

**Notes:**

- I couldn't find a way to pass the number directly to the formatter (as it takes only `String` as input), so I had to change the number to be a `String`. If you don't want to do that, then you'll have to write a custom converter anyway.
- You can replace `ZoneOffset.UTC` with any timezone you want (even `ZoneId.systemDefault()`), it'll depend on what your application needs. But as told in [@Ole V.V.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422616/jackson-deserialize-epoch-to-localdate/44440899#comment75846923_44422616), the timezone might cause the date to change.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot modify the structure of the JSON file. Nevertheless thank you for your answer.

Comment: Well thought out and researched.