# Deserialize LocalDateTime with Jackson

Tags: java, date, jackson

I have an error when I try to deserialize this attribute:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
private LocalDateTime deliveryDate;
```

This is the deserialization class:

```
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {

        if (parser.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)) {
            String rawDate = parser.getText();
            return LocalDateTime.parse(rawDate);
        } else {
            throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING, "Expected string.");
    }
}
```

And the serialization class:

```
public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
"timestamp":1513962011642,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Could not read document: Text '2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23
```

Do you know why?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)

Comment: What is the actual original data in the JSON? 1513962011642?

Comment: The original data is 2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Process as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) rather than [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
Instant.parse( "2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z" )
```

## Details

Not sure of your original data from JSON. If your input data is `1513962011642`, it appears to be a count since an epoch, presumably an [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, the first moment of 1970 in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_513_962_011_642L ) ;
```

If the original input is `2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z`, directly parse as an `Instant`. That string is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means UTC.

The java.time classes use the standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z" ) ;
```

A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) purposely lacks any concept of a [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), so it does *not* represent an actual moment and is not a point on the timeline.  You are mistakenly trying to fit your value into the wrong class, where the fact it is a UTC value cannot be represented.

Instead, process that input as an `Instant` object. An instant represents a point on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)  with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

Comment: `timestamp` `1513962011642` is the time of http request which isn't related with text date string which produces the error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error is pretty straightforward, it says that spring can't deserialize this string `"2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z"` to `LocalDateTime`.
If you will run the next code you will see the same error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-12-22T16:00:00.874Z"));
}
```

The source of the error is character `'Z'` at index 23. If you will remove this character the code above will work. So i would recommend you to check why this `'Z'` character is present in the string while your serializer doesn't add it.

Comment: Poor advice. Discarding the `Z` is throwing away information, the fact that this string represents a moment in UTC. The real issue is that the input should be processed as a `Instant` rather than as a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: While i admit that Z can be present it the string i didn't suggest to remove it. And the question isn't about necessity of presence of this character. The question is - why the error occurs, the answer is - deserializer can't deserialize such string because of presence of Z character which isn't added during serialization. And advice is to figure out why it is present. Different format on server and client could be the reason but i can't be such categorial as you because i don't have enough details.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)