# (De)serialising LocalDate: how to prepare JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a class that represent data in which there is `LocalDate` field.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private LocalDate dob;
    //getters and setters
}
```

In `pom.xml` I have `jackson-modules-java8` so that `Local`Date could be deserialized. I'm having difficulty preparing correct JSON to be able to send `POST`. Here it is:

```
{ "name" : "John", "dob" : [ 1986::10::06 ] }
```

In a response to `POST` I get `Cannot deserialize instance of`java.time.LocalDate`out of START_ARRAY token`. Decorating the field dob with annotation `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy::MM::dd")` didnn't work. Three years ago [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803634/2657875) was published but things may have changed since then.

Comment: That is not valid JSON. JSON has no Date type at all. What is about `"dob" : "[ 1986::10::06 ]"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) description of json values:

> In JSON, values must be one of the following data types:
>
> - a string
> - a number
> - an object (JSON object)
> - an array
> - a boolean
> - null

According this definition your json is not valid because `[1986::10::06]` is not a valid value.
You need to treat it as a string, adding the `"` characters around it instead of squared brackets.

The right json must be

```
{ "name" : "John", "dob" : "1986::10::06" }
```

Comment: This time I'm getting `Cannot deserialize instance of `java.time.LocalDate` out of START_ARRAY token`.

Comment: You are right. That happens because your date field is not an array. It is necessary to remove the square brackets. Check updated answer

Comment: Stil no luck. I'm getting `Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1986::10::06')`

Comment: @menteith that happens because there is no default constructor (a constructor without parameters) for LocalDate. You need to use a custom serializer deserializer to handle such kind of objects.

Comment: I cannot find an easy guide to writing custom deserializer. Could you link to some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The LocalDate API doc says:

> A date without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as
>   2007-12-03.

So you JSON should be like:

```
{ "name" : "John", "dob" : "1986-10-06" }
```

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDate` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1986-10-06')`.