# Jackson JSON output formatting

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an `ArrayList<Person>` that contains a few `Person` type objects. The `Person` class has the following attributes with their getters and setters:

```
private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private LocalDate birthDate;
```

I'd like to export the `ArrayList<Person>` to a `JSON` output file with the exact same format:
`persons.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Best",
    "email": "thenextbigthing@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1981-11-23"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Andy Jr.",
    "email": "usa@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1982-12-01"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "JohnDoe",
    "email": "gameover@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1990-01-02"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "SomeOne",
    "email": "rucksack@gmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1988-01-22"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Mr. Mxyzptlk",
    "email": "bigman@hotmail.com",
    "birthDate": "1977-08-12"
  }
]
```

I've tried to create an `Array` from the `ArrayList` and create the output from that `Array` but I have a problem with that which I cannot work it around. I'm getting output data for the `birthDate` attribute looking like this:

```
"birthDate" : {
    "year" : 1952,
    "month" : "JANUARY",
    "chronology" : {
      "id" : "ISO",
      "calendarType" : "iso8601"
    },
    "era" : "CE",
    "leapYear" : true,
    "dayOfMonth" : 27,
    "monthValue" : 1,
    "dayOfWeek" : "SUNDAY",
    "dayOfYear" : 27
  }
```

How can I make every attribute have the same output format as provided in the example `persons.json` output file. I'm not allowed to use any other Jackson library besides core, annotations and databind. I'm also not allowed to change attribute type inside the class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any other Jackson library besides core, annotations and databind.

Comment: Are you allowed to change field type from LocalDate to another one?

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use another Jackson library. What kind of nonsense policy is that?

Comment: The task is from a Java online course. They have an automatic evaluator on their site and it doesn't like external libraries. It cannot compile and evaluate the source code I upload unless I'm using libraries they tell me to use. No problem though, I have already figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void saveListToJSON(String fileName) throws
            MyCustomException {

        DateTimeFormatter dtf
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        ObjectNode newStud;
        int id;
        String name;
        String email;
        String birthDate;

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
        ArrayNode root = objectMapper.createArrayNode();

        for (Person person : this.persons) {
            newStud = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
            id = person.getId();
            name = person.getName();
            email = person.getEmail();
            birthDate = person.getBirthDate().format(dtf);
            newStud.put("id", id);
            newStud.put("name", name);
            newStud.put("email", email);
            newStud.put("birthDate", birthDate);
            root.add(newStud);
        }

        try {
            objectMapper.writeValue(new File(fileName), root);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new MyCustomException("The given output file "
                    + fileName + " cannot be opened for writing.");
        }
```

Comment: This gives me the output in the same format like in the provided example `JSON`.

Answer (score 3):

So if you're not allowed to add maven dependency of

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then you can write custom serializer for your class as below:

```
public class MyCustomSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Person value, JsonGenerator jgen,
                          SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        if (value != null) {
            jgen.writeStartObject();

            jgen.writeStringField("date", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value.getBirthDate()));
            // parse other fields here manually

            jgen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

and add below annotation to your Person.class:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
```

It parses date as :

```
{
    "date": "2018-08-23"
}
```

If you don't want to write custom serializer another alternative is to using @JsonGetter annotation but either you should add @JsonIgnore to birthDate field or give value as same name to @JsonGetter("sameAsFieldName"). If you give another value to your @JsonGetter and don't add @JsonIgnore to your field, it serialize both your field and @JsonGetter return value.

You can add a method to your class as below:

```
@JsonGetter("birthDate")
public String getSerializedLocalDate() {
    return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(this.getBirthDate());
}
```

Comment: is there no way to add an annotation to the relevant field only, and provide a serializer for that?

Comment: @WalterTross of course, you can add `@JsonSerialize` annotation to a field and change `JsonSerializer<Type>`. But for our example LocalDate, if we give `JsonSerializer<LocalDate>` and override serialize method as `jgen.writeStringField("date", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value.getBirthDate()));` , the serialized person includes `{ "birthDate" : { "date": "2018-08-24" } }` and it is not desired output. If we serialize just `jgen.writeString(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value.getBirthDate()));` it throws exception on runtime while serializing.

Comment: thanks, but there ought to be an easier way. Anyway, I would edit the answer, if I were you

Comment: @WalterTross I add another alternative solution using JsonGetter. So you don't have to write custom serializer. But there are some key points needs to be consider.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Jackson uses the mutators to create the JSON.  In the `getBirthDate` mutator return a formatted date using `SimpleDateFormatter` or one of the many Text formatters.

```
class Person {
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String email;
   private LocalDate birthDate;

   // MUTATORS HERE


   @JsonProperty("birthDate")
   public String getStringBirthDate(){
      // Turn to formatted (yyyy-mm-dd) String
   } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using `ObjectMapper`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // to enable java.time serializing
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);

    // just to format output
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    // JSON - your provided JSON file
    Person[] arrayList
            = mapper.readValue(JSON, Person[].class);

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(arrayList));
}
```

Comment: OP does not allowed to use jackson maven dependency jsr310