# Json array not serializing properly

Tags: java, jsonschema, jsonserializer

I am trying to Json serialize and deserialize LocalDate array in my Java class but when i generate json schema for the web service, the parameter still shows up as LocalDate rather than String.

Following is the code :

```
@JsonSerialize(
        contentUsing = ToStringSerializer.class
    )
    @JsonDeserialize(
        contentUsing = LocalDateFromJSON.class
    )
    private LocalDate[] amortizationDates;
```

and in Json schema this appears as :

```
amortizationDates":{"type":"array","items":{"$ref":"#/definitions/LocalDate"}}
```

which is wrong because it should appear as String when serialized.

Any ideas on how to serialize it as String.

Edit:

I am suing Jackson for serialization and following are serializer details :

`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.ToStringSerializer`- Jackson inbuilt

LocalDateFromJSON ->

```
public static class LocalDateFromJSON extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {
        public LocalDateFromJSON() {
        }

        public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
            return LocalDate.parse(((TextNode)jsonParser.readValueAsTree()).asText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need custom serialization format for LacalDate? Because you can just add this lib   `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310` to make jakson support java 8 time

Comment: check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format