# Convert LocalDate to "dd/MM/yyyy" using jackson annotations

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jackson-databind, localdate

I'm using:

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private LocalDate date;
```

But its not working...

What I receive in soapUi is:

```
"date":    {
  "year": 1995,
  "month": "OCTOBER",
  "dayOfMonth": 10,
  "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
  "era": "CE",
  "dayOfYear": 283,
  "leapYear": false,
  "monthValue": 10,
  "chronology":   {
     "id": "ISO",
     "calendarType": "iso8601"
  }
```

},

I should not need an objectmapper right?

is there a way to just use annotations?

Comment: @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", timezone="GMT")

Comment: Obviously Jackson ignores the annotation, and serialize `LocalDate` as a regular class. Did you [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)?

Comment: @VishalPatel the result is the same :(

Comment: @TiagoMachado check the below answer

Comment: Hello. It's unclear if your problem is serialization (you need to format date for response) or deserialization (you need to parse date from JSON request).

Comment: @Benoit i checked that but somehow it didnt work, now i tried again and it works like a charm, must have done some mistake there. thanks a lot bro

Comment: Did you look into [FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8) yet? Not that I got experience with it myself.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialization the LocalDateTime of Java8

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.deser.LocalDateDeserializer;

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

While using the following dependencies in your project.

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
   <version>2.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.7"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.7"
```

No additional implementation of Deserializer is required.

Answer (score -1):

Specifically, `@JsonFormat` allows you to specify how to format Date and Calendar values according to a SimpleDateFormat format.
Instead of using LocalDate, use Date then specify locale as this annotation's parameter.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", locale = "en_GB")
public Date getCurrentDate() {
    return new Date();
}
```

[Guide to @JsonFormat in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat)

Comment: Isn’t that a step backward? `Date` is poorly designed and long outdated (and despite the name doesn’t represent a date). `LocalDate` is the modern class to use for a date.