# How to convert LocalDate value in Map with Jackson serialization/deserialization?

Tags: spring-boot, serialization, java-8, jackson, jackson-modules

I have a class which looks like below:

```
class A {
Map<String, LocalDate> mapLocalDate;
Map<String, String> simpleMap;
String name;
}
```

This class should be converted to Map < String, Object >, where the key is the attribute name and the value is attribute value.
To do so I use the Jackson ObjectMapper:

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
    objectMapper.registerModules(new JavaTimeModule());

    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS, false);
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

final Map<String, Object> fieldMap = this.objectMapper.convertValue(entityA, Map.class)
```

This approach works fine for simple fields like: "simpleMap", "name". But not for one with value LocalDate (field name: "mapLocalDate")
The convertation throw the bellow error:

[image]

java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.time.LocalDate

**Maybe somebody faced a similar issue and could suggest what is wrong in configurations?**

Comment: Did you go through [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)?

Comment: yes, as you could see it is configured in the same way as described in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Speise what type is entityA ?

Comment: @sovannarithcheav, please look at the top of the question to "class A"