# How to use JSONB PostgreSQL to insert columns through JSON?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, jsonb

I have an entity, which is mapped to PostgreSQL, I want to use JSONB to be able to insert columns through JSON.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TB_ORDEM_MANUTENCAO")
@TypeDef(
        name = "jsonb",
        typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class
)
public class OrdemManutencao implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) // Cria automaticamente os ids
    private long id;

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dataManutencao;    

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipamento_id", unique = true)
    private Equipamento equipamento;

    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    private String propriedades;            

}
```

In Swagger, I try to add a Maintenance Order as follows:

```
{
  "propriedades" : [{"uf": "MG", "teste": "teste"}],
  "dataManutencao": "2020-04-04",
  "equipamento": {
    "id": 13,
    "nome": "Lavadoura",
    "quantidade": 1
  }
}
```

This does not insert the columns in my order_maintenance table, just insert like that:

```
Response body
{
  "id": 27,
  "dataManutencao": "2020-04-04",
  "equipamento": {
    "id": 13,
    "nome": "Lavadoura",
    "quantidade": 1
  }
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)

Comment: doesn't answer. I'm using Jsonb.

Comment: This gives a clue, maybe, https://thoughts-on-java.org/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solve to me: vladmihalcea.com/map-string-jpa-property-json-column-hibernate.