# Json Parse Error - MismatchedInputException expecting array or string for LocalDate in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, java-time, jsonparser

I have 2 microservices which communicate via REST call.
I have an Entity named Consumer which has various fields including a LocalDate.
When i pass this entity via REST call, i get the following exception

```
Json parse error expected array or string.,nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
```

In Entity class,i annotated like below

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate dateOfBirth
```

In application.properties, i added the below line,

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false
```

I am using Spring Boot version 2.1.2.RELEASE.
In pom.xml, i have jackson dependencies.

```
I have added jackson-databind and jackson-datatype-jsr310,
both versions 2.9.9
```

I am using Retrofit as the client in 1st microservice through which i make the REST call to the REST ENDPOINT(@RestController) of the 2nd microservice.

But i get the error - Json Parse Error - MismatchedInputException for LocalDate.
Is there anything more i need to add ?

**EDIT-1**
Following is the snippet of the generated JSON,

```
{"consumerId":1,"consumerName":"Harry","dateOfBirth":{"year":1991,"month":3,"day":10},"requestDate":"year":2020,"month":8,"day":31}
```

**EDIT-2**
I implemented following this link,
http://lewandowski.io/2016/02/formatting-java-time-with-spring-boot-using-json/

Additionally added below as suggested by @rohit in the comments.

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@JsonSerialize(using=LocalDateSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using=LocalDateDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate dateOfBirth
```

But still the date format generated in the JSON is not changing as per the format.

```
"dateOfBirth":{"year":1991,"month":3,"day":10}
```

It should be,

```
"dateOfBirth":"1991-03-10"
```

Isnt it ??

Is the bean defined in the SpringBoot main class not being used ?,

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper serializingObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaTimeModule javaTimeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    javaTimeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
    javaTimeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
    objectMapper.registerModule(javaTimeModule);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Now i am getting below error,

```
Json parse error: text; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: text (through reference chain com.model.Consumer["dateOfBirth"])
```

Comment: can you share input json or date field that is passed to this api

Comment: *"Json parse error **expected array or string**"* means that the actual JSON value is **not a string**, i.e. is not text formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd`. Check your assumptions, i.e. what the JSON value of property `dateOfBirth` actually is.

Comment: this might be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)

Comment: @rohithd - I have updated the question and added the generated JSON.

Comment: @Silhoutte - As per the link, I need to create a ContextResolver <ObjectMapper> bean in my SpringBoot Main class. ?. Also how to use the ObjectMapper in the RestController ? And do i have to format the Date using DateTimeFormatter before storing it in my Entity Object ?

Comment: if you are passing the jSON you need to fromat to date type required and as expected in the api that is being consumed

try adding
 @JsonFormat(pattern = "MM-dd-yyyy")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
in your entity class

Comment: @rohithd - I have updated the question after making the changes. But still getting error. I think it is not using the defined Object mapper ?

Comment: Consumer model is at receiving request ?
In Consumer model also follow the same .
refer link below
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2018/02/how-to-parse-json-with-date-field-in-java-jackson-example.html#:~:text=In%20order%20to%20correct%20deserialize,a%20date%20field%20in%20JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i was using Retrofit,

Added a registerTypeAdapter to my GsonBuilder as below,

```
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer());
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer());
```