# How to get LocalDate value in String format from JsonNode object?

Tags: objectmapper, jackson-databind, jsonnode

I am trying to get date value from JsonNode. I have a car object which has car name and released LocalDate.

```
public class Car {

  String carName;

  LocalDate released;

}
```

I need to convert it into JsonNode, so I am doing this way.

```
  ObjectMapper obj = new ObjectMapper();

  JsonNode node = obj.valueToTree(car);
```

Until here I am good. Once I have JsonNode I need to read it from it.

```
String carName = node.at("/carName").textValue();

LocalDate date = node.at("/released").textValue();
```

How can I get LocalDate value in LocalDate format or String format from JsonNode?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? If you want the text representation of the date, won't `String date = node.at("/released").textValue(); ` work then? I'm struggling to understand what you are trying to accomplish when you go from a concrete class to JsonNode and then try to read out the values.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into it. actually, I am trying this way, String date = node.at("/released").textValue();  but it is not working and unfortunately there is no method available like asDateValue(). So answer to your question, I need to get LocalDate value from JsonNode. it doesn't matter how and what I use. Hope this makes sense.Thanks again!

Comment: Ok so what happens when you call `.textValue()`?

Comment: I get null. for string value let's say I want to get carName, I can do .textValue() and able to get the string value.

Comment: Yeah, it’s probably not a string value. Check this post for options on how to change the serialization of a LocalDate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I used
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
I am able to get string value from JsonNode now.

Answer (score 0):

it worked. I used objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()); objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS); I am able to get string value from JsonNode now.