# How to deserialize date field with many formats to LocalDate variable

Tags: java, jackson, localdate

I have a simple DTO that I would like to receive as a JSON and deserialize using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`

```
class SimpleDto {
    LocalDate date;
}
```

The problem is that the format of this date, however should be `yyyy-MM-dd`, is not fixed and it can miss some parts - e.g. it can be full date

```
{
    "date": "2020-01-01"
}
```

or just year with month without day

```
{
    "date": "2020-01"
}
```

or even just a year

```
{
    "date": "2020"
}
```

I'm trying to use `ObjectMapper` with `JavaTimeModule` registered but it does not support e.g. year without month and day format

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(JavaTimeModule());
```

is it possible to map it somehow to `LocalDate`? I saw some similar topics (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format)) but seems that they're do not answer my question

---

**EDIT**

Now I'm starting to think should I treat this field as a `LocalDate` - as far as I understand there's nothing like `LocalDate.of(2000, 0, 0)` (and actually it's throwing exception) then deserializing `1990` to (what?) `1990-01-01` is obviously an error and could cause some exceptions in a logic that would assume that `01` is a valid and provided month and `01` is a valid and provided day

Answer (score 2):

You can create your custom serializer having a `DateTimeFormatter` built using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder#parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Test
        Stream.of(
                    "2020-01-01",
                    "2020-01",
                    "2020"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(parseToLocalDate(s)));
    }
    static LocalDate parseToLocalDate(String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("u[-M[-d]]")
                                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
                                    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
                                    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
        
        return LocalDate.parse(date, dtf);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-01-01
2020-01-01
2020-01-01
```

The pattern, `u[-M[-d]]` has optional fields inside square brackets.

Answer (score 1):

How about extending LocalDateDeserializer and then use @JsonSerialize(using = YourLocalDateSerializer.class)

Comment: sounds like something that could work however I would like to avoid putting annotation over every `LocalDate` field - I have many of them

Comment: And all of these may come in these truncated formats? It’s best to limit the user of the custom deserializer to where it’s actually needed.

Answer (score 0):

A `LocalDate` can hold only a valid date. I understand from your edit that you don’t want a date of January 1, 2020 in case only a year, 2020, was present in your JSON input. You may build a custom deserializer around the following code, but it will have some drawbacks.

```
public TemporalAccessor deserialize(String inputDate) {
    switch (inputDate.length()) {
    case 10:
        return LocalDate.parse(inputDate);
    case 7:
        return YearMonth.parse(inputDate);
    case 4:
        return Year.parse(inputDate);
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid input date: " + inputDate);
    }
}
```

It will be unpractical that you don’t know the exact type of the result, manageable, though. And you will be sure that if the parsed value includes a month or a day of month, then those come from the input. For a demonstration:

```
    String[] exampleInputs = { "2020-01-01", "2020-01", "2020" };
    for (String example : exampleInputs) {
        TemporalAccessor parsed = deserialize(example);
        System.out.format(
                "%-10s parsed into %-10s, a %-9s. Has month? %-5b Has day? %b%n",
                example, parsed, parsed.getClass().getSimpleName(),
                parsed.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR),
                parsed.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    }
```

Output is:

> ```
> 2020-01-01 parsed into 2020-01-01, a LocalDate. Has month? true  Has day? true
> 2020-01    parsed into 2020-01   , a YearMonth. Has month? true  Has day? false
> 2020       parsed into 2020      , a Year     . Has month? false Has day? false
> ```