# How to properly convert dto to json in Java?

Tags: java, json, object, objectmapper

How to properly convert dto to json in Java? I do it like below with using `ObjectMapper`:

```
        ObjectDto dto;
        byte[] json = new byte[0];

        dto = service.getDto(someId);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        json = mapper.writeValueAsBytes(dto);
```

and the problem is in formatting `date` field. In Dto i have my date in this format: `2021-09-27T12:06:27.990Z` but after convert this dto to json in bytes, I see that my `date` is split into object with many properties like below:

```
"date":{
         "year":2021,
         "month":"OCTOBER",
         "nano":528000000,
         "monthValue":10,
         "dayOfMonth":25,
         "hour":13,
         "minute":14,
         "second":58,
         "dayOfYear":298,
         "dayOfWeek":"MONDAY",
         "chronology":{
            "id":"ISO",
            "calendarType":"iso8601"
         }
      },
```

I want to, after using `ObjectMapper` to have all property from `Dto` in this same format as before convert. How to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the datatype of `creationTime` in your DTO?

Comment: this is my `date`, I paste bad json

Comment: i'm fix it.....

Comment: `LocalDateTime`

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your DTO with the @JsonFormat Annotation? See the Documentation here: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html And for some examples here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat

Comment: I cannot use any of the annotation cause I work on auto-generated dto's :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 LocalDate Jackson format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format) (Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35062824).)

Comment: Good point @Ivar the SerializationFeature configuration should do the trick.

Comment: @Ivar I use it and this convert my date but without "Z" at the end of the date, so still throw me an exception

Comment: Can't you change whatever is auto-generating the DTO's, to use a `String` for the date field instead of a `LocalDateTime` and make sure that this string contains the correct value? Might save you some trouble.

Comment: it format me to this type: `"creationTime":"2021-10-25T13:14:58+02:00",` which is not this same as in dto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register a custom serializer

```
public class ItemSerializer extends StdSerializer<Item> {
  ....
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Item.class, new ItemSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

See the full explanation here : https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Answer (score 0):

Use DataType of your Date as String in your DTO. It will solve the problem