# Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to do a POST:
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.OffsetDateTime` from String "2021-04-08T05:00:25": Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2021-04-08T05:00:25'

and I'm using these

```
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private OffsetDateTime createDate = null;


  @JsonProperty("finish_date")
  @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  private OffsetDateTime finishDate = null;
```

and my JSON are these:

```
  "create_date": "2021-04-08T05:00:25",
  "finish_date": "2021-04-08T05:00:25",
```

Comment: You are trying to parse into an `OffsetDateTime` with no offset info in the input string.
Try using `LocalDateTime` instead

Comment: BTW your pattern needs to be `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: I still have same error.. Another question: I'm mapping these dates with Types.DATA, because in my oracle database, the parameter is set as SYSDATE.

Comment: maybe this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format