# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate`

Tags: json, spring-boot

Im trying to send a post to my api using postman:

[image]

But its returning an error:

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "10/11/2022": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '10/11/2022' could not be parsed at index 0;

I tried to correct do the mapping with json mapping annotation in the dto class:

```
@Data
@Builder
public class OfertaEspecialDTO {

    private String nome;
    private final double desconto_percentual;
    private String descricao;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate dataValidade;
}
```

But its still returning me the error.

How is the correct way to map my dateTime instance variable?

Comment: Did you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28802544/java-8-localdate-jackson-format?

Comment: I just implemented this solution but its still not working

Comment: Check for ObjectMapper with DateTime option, i don't remember exactly but it is related to that, i faced this long back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with `LocalDate` instance variable mapping. Issue is with annotations used on top of class. Please refactor DTO class like this and try again.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class OfertaEspecialDTO {
    private String nome;
    private double desconto_percentual;
    private String descricao;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate dataValidade;
}
```

or like this

```
@Data
public class OfertaEspecialDTO {
    private String nome;
    private double desconto_percentual;
    private String descricao;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate dataValidade;
}
```

Comment: Removing the @Builder annotation returns me the following error:     "message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.launchersoft.vouchersapi.dto.OfertaEspecialDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.launchersoft.vouchersapi.dto.OfertaEspecialDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no

Comment: Yes you need to remove final keyword from desconto_percentual variable. Then this error will be gone. Please check my solution I am not using final keyword

Comment: If my solution helps then request you to please accept the answer so that it help others as well.